# Computer freezing in-game

Tags: technical-issues

I have an HP dv6 laptop, with an i7 3rd generation processor, 8GB of RAM, a Nvidia Geoforce GT 630M graphics card, and it is running Windows 64 bit.

I am able to play games like Borderlands 2 perfectly fine, but recently my computer has been freezing in-game. The audio continues to play, but the screen is completely frozen. I can't even use ctrl+alt+delete to pull up the task manager to shut down the game. I have to turn off my computer completely. This is incredibly annoying.

It has happened while playing Borderlands 2, but only once in the 30 some hours I have played it. It has also happened while playing League of Legends, Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2, Call of Duty: World at War, Resident Evil 5 (I think), and Metro 2033. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share why you downvoted this so that I can prevent further errors in the future.

Comment: Have you done all your windows updates and updated your video drivers? As far as the downvotes I'm not sure why you got them, but it's all one huge glob. Some structuring would be nice.

Comment: I have my windows updates automatically install every week, but I will check that. I went to the Nvidia site and had it check my system for what driver I needed. It didn't show that I even had a driver at all, and I know that I have updated my driver on multiple occasions. Nevertheless, I will install the suggested one and see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: What specific version of Windows are you running? Does this ever occur when you play games in windowed mode? What's the system uptime when this happens?

Comment: Typically intermittent problems that occur after you've been playing for a while are heat related - try to make sure you have proper circulation around the laptop (ie, not blocking any fan grills or similar).  Adding a small desk fan or propping the unit up might help.

Comment: @Yves I've got Windows 7 Home Premium, if that's what you're asking. It doesn't take the computer any longer to boot up again after it happens if I start it up normally. Maybe like 45 seconds to a little over a minute

Comment: Try to minimize programs running in the background too. Try [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) or [CCleaner's startup tool](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

Comment: I have a Sony Vaio (god knows why I bought that...) and it has major overheating issues especially when watching movies or playing games on it. If I don't use a cooling pad, it freezes, I mean it freezes the OS and C-A-Del doesn't do anything and only a restart fixes it. It now sits in a corner collecting dust or sometimes gets used as a pad to put my food on while I eat and watch TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said, these are just advices:

> Make sure your drivers are up to date.

Keep updated drivers ensures better functioning and less possibility of error being generated by them.

> Keep proper cooling

In my opinion, hp notebooks tend to get very hot during operation of games that require a lot of graphics. Make sure the air outlet of your notebook is not blocked, and that the coolers are working properly.

Overheating may have caused the freezing to avoid damage to the processor.

Comment: Drivers dont get damaged!! Processors do. You probably have your last statement the wrong way around!

Comment: @SamyamA, you are right, i'm editing my answer right now. Thank you .

Comment: +1 for mentioning heat. OP's problems sound like they could be caused by dust buildup/vents being blocked.

Comment: Ok cool. I have a cooling pad that I use but sometimes I don't remember or am too lazy to use it. I've updated my video driver so hopefully it won't happen as much or at all.

Comment: fyi, drivers can get damaged, just as any data on a machine can get damaged. It usually isn't likely. But by overheating you are most likely to damage the processor. Modern machines freeze to prevent that damage. (If they do not, they just crash and burn).